# Regex Differences PHP 5.3 to 5.4

Tags: php, regex

On my development system I had no choice but to install PHP5.4, but the live server is PHP5.3

I wrote the following line of code to remove the `data:major/minor;base64,` from the beginning of JavaScript base64 encoded string.

```
preg_replace("/^data\:(:?.*)?base64\,(.*)/", "$2", $src)
```

It worked on my dev machine, but didn't work on the live system. My question is, regardless of whether it is correct or not, **why did it work in PHP5.4 but not in PHP5.3?** What are the differences in the regex engine that I should look out for? The next question is if the regex is wrong, how should it look?

Comment: Abuse of tag `javascript`.

Comment: Ergh... 5.4 on dev, 5.3 in prod ? You are going to get some problems. I'll suggest you to kidnap your sys admin and force him to setup a 5.3.

Comment: @michail_w It was a suggested tag. SO suggested PHP regex and javascript. Copy and Paste into a new question and it will do the same for you

Comment: @KevinLabécot I am he :v ... almost (CentOS server, Ubuntu workstation)

Comment: Nothing related to `preg_replace` changed from 5.3 to 5.4. It must be something else. Tested it here with various versions ranging from 5.3.0 to 5.5.5: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea3ca18c100dff425ba72a4d86ac057a8c4f22f0

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Errors? Incorrect result?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this regex:

```
^data\:[^\?]*?base64\,(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/AUS0v2lL74wWpJxT)

Comment: Could you explain what the regex does section for section for others?

Comment: This is not section for section, you just have to match all characters without `?` char. Because `?` is delimiter, you shouldn't use `.*`, because it can match whole text to his end, and other parts wouldn't be matched.

Comment: It looks like a good answer for half of the problem. I did things the long way round instead to be safe. But thanks

Comment: fyi, you do not need to escape `?` inside a character class